# pip install cryptography fail with "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required."

Tags: python

To "install pyOpenSSL", I need "pip install cryptography" first. Got below error when install the cryptography.

After I installed the VC++ 10.0 in my PC. Still got same error.

Can someone give me a suggestion that how to fix this issue?

Python version: 3.3

Error:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: Do you install the correct place? whether your `pip` refer to the `Python version: 3.3`?

Comment: Did you reboot after installing? At a minimum, you need to close the command prompt and reopen it.

Comment: @aircraft   :Is there special place to install SDP7.1? I just installed it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1, and add the dir into sys variable $path.    and pip refer to python3.3 already.

Comment: @sytech  I rebooted my computer and still got the same error.